# Is it possible to convert timestamp to date and time using GMT offset as timezone in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a couple of GMT time zones like this:

```
GMT-06:00
GMT-05:00
GMT-04:00
```

Right now I am using this to convert a time stamp into a date and time like this:

```
formatted = moment(timestamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z');
```

Which returns something like `2018-07-02 14:15:03`

But the date and time are returned in my local time. I was wondering if moment.js allows me to supply a GMT timezone, and have the date and time be returned in the local time of that specific time zone.

I know that moment.js allows me to do this:

```
moment(timestamp).tz("Africa/Accra").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z');
```

which would return the date and time in that specific "Africa/Accra" time zone, however, I can't use that because I only have GMT time zones right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTC and GMT indicate the same time. Convert the Local time to `UTC` and then use `utcOffset`.

```js
var m = moment(new Date()).utc().utcOffset("-06:00").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z");
console.log("UTC-06:00 -> " + m);
var m = moment(new Date()).utc().utcOffset("-05:00").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z");
console.log("UTC-05:00 -> " + m);
var m = moment(new Date()).utc().utcOffset("-04:00").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z");
console.log("UTC-04:00 -> " + m);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```